# How to hide an element if I click anywhere but inside in, but also run javascript inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, stoppropagation

I have a menu button, and if you click it, a menu drops down. Then, if you click anywhere on the HTML except for the menu or the button, the menu disappears. I achieved this by using jquery `stopPropogation` to prevent the `$("html").click` event from being triggered if the menu or button are clicked.

However, I added a link to my menu that uses `method: :delete`, and since jquery is disabled within the menu, the `method: :delete` is ignored as well, and the link sends a GET request.

Is it possible to achieve a menu that closes if you click anywhere but inside the menu or the menu button, but also have a `method: :delete` link?

```
<div id="menu-button">BUTTON</div>
<div id="menu">
  <%= link_to "LOG OUT", logout_path, method: :delete %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#menu-button").click(function() {
    $("#menu").toggle();
  });
  $("html").click(function() {
    $("#menu").hide();
  });
  $("#menu, #menu-button").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmyf1j3z/4/)

Comment: Where exactly are you planning to include this delete link? Is it within the menu or as separate element in the page? Could you just clarify on this or just update the fiddle with the delete link.

Comment: @Beginner I wasn't sure how to add the link, because it's an in-app path, but I added a basic link to the fiddle that demonstrates what I'm trying to to.